# How to draw a circle on MapBox MGLMapView?

Tags: ios, overlay, mapbox

I'm using MapBox SDK 3.1.1 for iOS, and it doesn't seem there's a way to draw a circle as an overlay (Polygons are included as primitives)

There used to be a way on the legacy SDK, but it's no longer maintained.

Can someone provide insights?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested, there's currently no replacement for RMCircle (present in in 1.x version) in the 3.1 SDK.

There's a workaround described here, that uses MapBox annotations

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2167#issuecomment-169265375

Look for

```
- (MGLPolygon*)polygonCircleForCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate withMeterRadius:(double)meterRadius
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what friedbunny suggested (and based on info in the link he posted), you can fix the zoom level, and use metersperpixelatlatitude to make an image of fixed size for your annotation.  Then, use the imageForAnnotation MGLMapViewDelegate callback to provide the "overlay" as the MGLAnnotationImage.

If you want to change zoom levels with this method though, you're looking at some pretty tricky juggling of delegate methods and possibly several minor hacks.